# SVG + Chrome: Strange Rendering with Many Circles

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, svg

I'm plotting thousands of SVG circle elements on chrome with d3, and am running into weird rendering issues. It seems that paths are being drawn between the circles. These elements have mouseover events, and when mousing over them, that small portion of the screen redraws and removes the weird paths from that area, but after mouseout, it goes back to the weird lines.

The expected behavior works on Safari, but nothing is drawn at all in Firefox.

I've had a hard time figuring out how to get this to work on Chrome. I previously made a smaller instance of the behavior disappear by removing the 'crispEdges' attribute in the circle's CSS, but that is not working anymore. Also, I have been able to successfully render these points in Chrome before- not sure why it's starting to act like this now.

Anyone have any ideas about why this is happening and what I can do to get this working on Chrome? Any input is greatly appreciated!

==============

Chrome Version: 56.0.2924.87

Safari Version: 10.0

JS code for drawing circles:

```
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, xMax])
    .range([0, width - margin.right]); 

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, yMax])
    .range([height - margin.top, 0]);

  var x = function(d) { return xScale(d.x); }  
  var y = function(d) { return yScale(d.y); }

  svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .attr("cx", x) 
        .attr("cy", y)
        .style("fill", colors)
        .on("mouseover", function(d,i){
          tooltip.html(toolTipHTML(d))
           .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
          return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d){
          return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
        });
```

CSS:

```
circle { 
  fill: black;
  stroke: none;
  shape-rendering: auto;
}
```

In Chrome: 
[image: lines randomly drawn between points]

In Safari:

[image: expected behavior]

===========

EDIT: [Small demo on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CjOmZIKJOnfFwcJrZuG6?p=preview)

I was able to reproduce the issue once on plunkr, but then after refresh, it went away. I tried to add more data to get it to reproduce again, but received a '400- Bad Request' response from plunkr. Sometimes when you zoom in on the circles, the random 'extraneous lines' show up, but they go away randomly. Anyways, here's the code if it helps. The original issue I've explained above is still an issue, even after refreshing multiple times. Any thoughts on how to move forward with this is greatly appreciated!

==============

EDIT 2/9: This may potentially be a hardware issue. 
I'm using a Macbook Air, early 2015; running macOS Sierra 10.12.
As I mentioned in the comments, I recorded a short video of the strange behavior that happens when I zoom into the Plunker demo, in case it gives a better description of the issue than I've been able to give with words alone:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saAm6Rim0zw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Provide a JSFiddle so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: There's no r attribute on your circles, which is why Firefox draws nothing.

Comment: When setting `cx` and `cy` like `.attr("cx", x)` and `.attr("cy", y)`, what are `x` and `y`?

Comment: @Gilsha I would, but the problem only seems to show up for a very large number of points. What would you suggest to do to create a JSFiddle to demonstrate the large scale? Should I make a large set of replica data?

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks! Adding the radius fixes it on Firefox; Chrome behavior still like the screenshot above, though

Comment: @altocumulus just added an edit with what x and y are!

Comment: @Bethany I cannot believe *that* is actually working! The setup for `x` and `y` looks just plain wrong... Please, have a look at the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#_continuous). The parameter to the scale isn't supposed to be a function.

Comment: @altocumulus apologies! I added the wrong code; just made an edit and it should now make more sense. I do not think this is necessarily an issue with the scaling of x and y's though, especially since positioning of the circles works on other browsers and it was working on Chrome for a smaller set of data.

Comment: @Bethany Try plnkr.co for setting up a demo. You can include much larger files than you can in JSFiddle.

Comment: @altocumulus, added a plunker. as i mentioned in my edit, i was only able to reproduce the issue once, but it went away after refresh. My original issue from my initial post persists even after refresh. I think it's an issue with having too many svg elements at once, but it feels like it should be something fixable since it works on Firefox and Safari. Thank you all for your comments and suggestions!

Comment: @Bethany I cannot reproduce this issue. Even if I use dynamically created data consisting of 100k objects.

Comment: That's very strange. Perhaps it's a hardware issue. Thank you for looking into this! I've uploaded a video of the issue from my end (the issue occurs on plunker after a couple times of zooming in). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saAm6Rim0zw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @Bethany Wow, that is something! Have you considered filing a bug report? For me it work with the following version containing 50k dynmically generated objects: http://plnkr.co/edit/cuMdiOaLiRorTJKJW4sB?p=preview.

Comment: Hm, your plunker doesn't show up for me (it says "Bad Request" in the previewer frame). I'll file a bug report now! Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone following this post, as of about 2 days ago, a bug was reported on Chromium by someone else with the issue (Chrome on Mac):

[Chromium Bug Report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=690144&q=svg&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified#)

Comment: *"...by someone else..."* Looks like that someone is Mike Bostock himself ;-)